# Need a Python code to convert a secret key to base64 encoded

Tags: python, base64, secret-key

I have a secret key generated - A0[Bt"V59.xA-bKO|/A""/Z.!#Y:wfpR , need to convert this to base64 encoded format , Please help with the python code to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Answer (score 3):

For encoding to base64 use the `base64` module and its function `b64encode` for that.

Example -

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode("Hello")
'SGVsbG8='
>>> s = 'A0[Bt\"V59.xA-bKO|/A\"\"/Z.!#Y:wfpR'
>>> base64.b64encode(s)
'QTBbQnQiVjU5LnhBLWJLT3wvQSIiL1ouISNZOndmcFI='
```

For decoding , use the `b64decode()` function -

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode('SGVsbG8=')
'Hello'
>>> base64.b64decode('QTBbQnQiVjU5LnhBLWJLT3wvQSIiL1ouISNZOndmcFI=')
'A0[Bt"V59.xA-bKO|/A""/Z.!#Y:wfpR'
```